# Is there a way to select to a character in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I've just migrated from vim and one thinkg I miss is the motions like `vi(` or `vf<char>`. Is there a way to do something similar in Emacs? Perhaps it is possible to get isearch to select from *here* to the match?

Comment: control-space sets mark, is it which you want?

Comment: @aaacarp you're onto something there. Thanks! Put this in as an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

control-space sets the mark.  region from Mark to cursor position is selected.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Setting-Mark.html

Comment: to continue this theme ctrl-r performs an incremental search backwords and ctrl-s performs an incremental search forwards. In both cases, it expands the selected region appropriately.

Comment: @MDC it would also be good to look through emacs wiki website, http://www.emacswiki.org/

Comment: I do spend a lot of time there. There's just so much!

Comment: The mark is implicit when you use C-s or C-r, so C-s <char> marks the region from point to first occurence of <char>. Example: C-s foo RET C-w kills everything from point to (and including) the string 'foo'.